# Report State return error 503 after QUERY

Tags: google-smart-home

After initial SYNC and following QUERY, my action will process a Report State to upload the current states of devices to Home Graph, but receive an error 503 which causes an error message "Could not update setting. Check your connection", even the devices are added correctly. This brings a really bad user experience when Account Linking, does anyone see this error before?

Comment: How long after syncing do you report state?

Comment: The problem is caused by my instance is not able to handle too many incoming requests, it is solved by changing to automatic scaling. Thanks for checking it.

Answer (score 0):

The 503 code indicates a Service Unavailable error, which might be due to the timing of your report states. The error you mentioned shown to the users is most likely caused by the error you have on your action, and is not part of the intended account linking / sync flow. If you are continuing to have this issue, please file a ticket on our public issue tracker → https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=655104&template=1284148